# Gzip in apache-tomcat

Tags: .htaccess, tomcat, gzip, deflate

I want to enable gzip for compression and I have tried many blocks of code. Unfortunately, nothing works. The server that my host is using is apache-tomcat. Do they use different code for enabling gzip or deflate? I only have access to .htaccess. Can someone please post the proper code for enabling gzip (or deflate) on apache-tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.htaccess` in Tomcat. This file belongs to the Apache Web Server. GZIP compression can be enabled in the [HTTP connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation). Your question is for serverfault and not stackoverflow.